# How to delete file by keyword with button press

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that will move or delete files by specific qualities (ie. keyword, last modified date, file type). I have a radio button for each option with a drop down box with options to archive or delete, and a text box for the keyword option and drop-downs for file type and last modified date. Attached is the sub for the button that will be executing these actions and the start of the action for the first option.  My question is: How can I delete or move these files based on their specifications? (filepath variable is the directory it will be working in)

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        Dim filepath As String
        Dim keyword As String
        keyword = boxKeyword.Text
        filepath = txtPathBox.Text
        Dim fileList1 As String() = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, keyword)



        If btnOption1.Checked = True Then
            If boxOption1.SelectedText = "Delete" Then

                For Each file As String In fileList1
                    MessageBox.Show(file, "will be deleted")
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file)
                Next

            End If
        End If



    End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look into the `System.IO` namespace and especially into the `Directory` / `DirectoryInfo` and `File` / `FileInfo` classes. They contain everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a structure like this, and check what you need inside the loop to decide if the file has to be moved or not...

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = txtPathBox.Text
    For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath)
        'strFile gets the full path + filename (Example: C:\Folder1\myFile.txt)
        If btnOption1.Checked = True Then
            'Move File?
        ElseIf ... Then
            'Move File?
        ElseIf ... Then
            'Move File?
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```